# Automatically generate date for insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group of insert statements below. The only difference between them is the `Thru_DT`. The first insert is for `6/30/2019` date. The second is for 15 days before that date and the third is for 15 days before the second insert's date. How do I generate these dates automatically without having to hard code them?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT t2.a1, Max(t2.b1) Provider, t2.c1
From table2 t2
LEFT JOIN tb t1 On t2.a = t1.a1
WHERE t1.b Is Null And t2.Thru_DT >= '6/30/2019' 
    And t2.c In (Select CCN From table3)

INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT t2.a1, Max(t2.b1) Provider, t2.c1
From table2 t2
LEFT JOIN tb t1 On t2.a = t1.a1
WHERE t1.b Is Null And t2.Thru_DT >= '6/15/2019' 
    And t2.c In (Select CCN From table3)

INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT t2.a1, Max(t2.b1) Provider, t2.c1
From table2 t2
LEFT JOIN tb t1 On t2.a = t1.a1
WHERE t1.b Is Null And t2.Thru_DT >= '6/1/2019' 
    And t2.c In (Select CCN From table3)
```

Comment: What is the pattern of generating the dates?

Comment: Every 15 days. @AnkitBajpai

Comment: In which programming language and environment are you generating these query strings?

Comment: `SQL`. It is a stored procedure. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Store the initial date as a variable, and use date math?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the dates in a CTE:

```
;WITH cte_date(thru_DT)
AS
(
  SELECT @GivenDate 
  UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-15,@GivenDate)
  UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-30,@GivenDate)
)
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT t2.a1, Max(t2.b1) Provider, t2.c1
From table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.c=t3.CCN
INNER JOIN cte_date d
ON t2.Thru_DT >= d.Thru_DT 
LEFT JOIN tb t1 On t2.a = t1.a1
WHERE t1.b Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a table constructor:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
    SELECT t2.a1, Max(t2.b1) Provider, t2.c1
    FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
         tb t1 
         ON t2.a = t1.a1 CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES ('2019-06-30'), ('2019-06-15'), ('2019-06-01')
         ) v(Thru_DT)
     WHERE t1.b Is Null AND
           t2.Thru_DT >= v.Thru_DT AND
           t2.c IN (SELECT CCN FROM table3);
```

Comment: I want to avoid hard coding the dates in there.

Comment: @Aaron . . . Your question is about hard-coded dates.  This answers your question (as I think the other answer does as well).  If you have a *different* question, I would suggest that you ask it as a *new* question.